# Combine date and time; ValueError: hour must be in 0..23

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following df:

```
date                             time
2018-01-01 00:00:00             7:30:33
2017-01-01 00:00:00             7:30:33
```

I  want to create a datetime column that should look like this:

```
2018-01-01 7:30:33        
2017-01-01 7:30:33
```

To do this I use the following code:

```
    df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].apply(str)+' '+df['time'])
```

It works the majority of the time. However, in some parts of my df (I dont know which parts), I get the following error:

```
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert `date` to `datetime`, and `time` to `timedelta`, and just sum 'em up.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date) + pd.to_timedelta(df.time)

0   2018-01-01 07:30:33
1   2017-01-01 07:30:33
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If you're worried about invalid values, add the `errors='coerce'` argument to both functions to handle them appropriately.